# GPRS Information - Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, gprs

I have almost the worst spec in the world. An application that exists and used to work. My aim is to recreate this app and make it work.

It's a *very* simple util that just displays the following information to screen:

- ARFCN - Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number
- LAC -  Location Area Code of the cell (unique in PLMN)
- RAC - Routing Area Identifier Code of the cell (unique in PLMN)
- MNC / MCC - Mobile Network Code / Mobile Country Code
- NCellInfo1-6 - ?
- Rx Quality -
- Frequency Hopping -
- Last registered network
- TMSI - ?
- Periodic Location Update value
- Band
- Channel in use
- RSSI 1 - received signal strength indication
- Last call release cause

I'm hoping I can gain some of this information via OpenNETCF's network information, maybe some P/Invokes somewhere or (worst case scenario) some kind of custom SDK that i'll need to find for the device (and its a niche device so I hope this isn't the case).

However wishing to utilise the powers of Stackoverflow I wondered if someone would be able to point me in the right direction to get this data off a device. Anyone know of any libs that specifically provide this kind of information?

Comment: You may want to be more specific about the device...

Comment: I'm pretty sure my only option is a generic lib of sorts as I doubt many people have developed for the: Mobile Compia - M3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for all of that information, but most of it you can get from RIL (Radio Interface Layer).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920475.aspx

I'm not sure that you will be able to use C# to access the RIL layer as you have to provide C function callbacks.

The cell tower information you get from RIL_GetCellTowerInfo function and the signal quality information you get from RIL_GetSignalQuality function.  Browse the MSDN documentation for the inforation you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

OpenNETCF's NetworkInformation namespace is not going to help - it's a wrapper around NDIS and WZC, which is not of much use for telephony.  What is probebly relevent here is the [Telephony API (TAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450239.aspx), though I have doubts whether even TAPI is going to give all of this info (it's been a while since I fought with TAPI).

My guess is that you'll be able to get some of the info through TAPI, but a lot of it i probably retrieved through a proprietary API that the radio vendor provides, and without info on that API (from the radio vendor or the device OEM) you're probably out of luck.